# Dictionary problems: results.Read<NotificationRule>().ToDictionary(rule => rule.Id) states duplicate key

Tags: c#

I have a slight problem I don't seem to understand.

I have this bit of code:

```
SELECT sr.RuleId, s.Id, s.Name FROM Sites s
INNER JOIN NotificationSiteRules sr ON s.Id = sr.SiteID
WHERE sr.RuleId IN (
    SELECT r.Id FROM NotificationRules r 
    INNER JOIN NotificationSiteRules sr ON r.Id = sr.RuleId
    WHERE r.IsDeleted = 0 AND (@siteId IS NULL OR sr.SiteId = @siteId)
)
```

which returns the following set:

```
1   1   SiteOne
3   1   SiteOne
7   1   SiteOne
1   5   SiteTwo
```

As you can see, for rule 1 I have both SiteOne and SiteTwo. This must be permitted.

The definition of NotificationRule object is:

```
public class NotificationRule
{
    public NotificationRule()
    {
        Sites = new List<Site>();
        Recipients = new List<Recipient>();
    }

    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public List<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }

}
```

So in this definition, it's actually stated that by each Id I should be able to have a *list* of Sites... But I am getting

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

when I do

```
var rules = results.Read<NotificationRule>().ToDictionary(rule => rule.Id);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I am editing the question because I am afraid I was not clear as to what I am trying to achieve.

The final result I was hoping for is of this form:

```
{1, [1,5],[SiteOne, SiteTwo]}
```

Which would correspond to:

```
{Key, List<Recipient>, list<Site>}
```

As you can see, in this construct I wouldn't have two keys, because all ends up into the same element.

Comment: within a `Dictionary` the key must be unique - the `1` appears 3x in your example

Comment: You can use a composite key for the dictionary to make it unique. Maybe a tuple of RuleID and Id?

Comment: Yes! If you [follow the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8), you'll see that a `Dictionary` cannot have duplicate keys and will throw an `ArgumentException` if this occurs.

Comment: Why not just do a third join instead of using a subquery?

Comment: Hi @fubo, I realize that I have the same key twice (the key is on the first column, number 1 appears twice), but what I am trying to create is a construct that takes the second and third items as "list", which would give me the following result: {[1,[1,5],[SiteOne,SiteTwo]}

Comment: "This must be permitted", well then you can't use `ToDictionary`. Use `ToLookup` instead, which for each key returns a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just found that the problem is not in that little bit of code; that one is handled ok. The problem is that @siteId is arriving null, and then I get duplicates in a *previous* query.
I am closing this question as the point is now moot; I need to figure out a way to fix the previous query to get me the correct value... or a way to handle that null. 
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be wanting to do a group by rather than creating a dictionary.

`var rules = results.Read<NotificationRule>().GroupBy(k => rule.Id);`
This will group the rules by `rule.Id`

or if you are just trying to get the sites for a specific rule you could do

`var siteId = 1;
var sites = results.Read<NotificationRule>().Where(r => r.Id == siteId);`

Comment: I think the group is what I was looking for, thank you! I am trying to retrieve the multiple relationships, I am afraid. It's for the view in which I list all rules; and if the rule applies to two sites, then it should be shown like that; applying to two sites. I have another implementation for getting the ones for a specific site. :)  I am testing the "GroupBy" now. :)

Comment: I figured out that the problem was actually higher up, in a previous conditional query. I was _actually_ getting duplicate lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as objects in the collection `results` have not unique values in the field `Id` you have to group results before put them to the dictionary.

```
results.Read<NotificationRule>()
  .GroupBy(rule=>rule.Id).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group=>group.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work as I hoped, since I cannot address it like `results.Read<inte, Site, int>((ruleId, s) => { rule[ruleId].Sites.Add(s); }`, since after the creation of the dictionary with the group, I don't have a construct rule[ruleId].Sites anymore... But I still think that the key is in your answer, so I keep working with it. :)

Comment: @OlgaAkselrad replace `group=>group.ToArray()` to `group=>group.ToList()`